# Ask Ubuntu support rules

Tags: discussion, end-of-support

I want to ask what the rules are for asking for help here, because I have several times been turned down by senior members just because I run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

It is my understanding from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases that 16.04 LTS is supported until 2026, so why the refusal to offer help to Ubuntu 16.04 users?